Subpar Results of Historical Portfolio Optimization with Few Assets
Probably a simple question to the P-Quants here, but if you performed portfolio optimization using a historically calibrated covariance matrix (a rolling month of daily returns) with very few assets, say 3 European ETFs with daily rebalancing across 10 years, is it possible for the performance metrics (based on a maximum Sharpe optimization) across these 10 years to be poorer than an equal-weighted portfolio?
Inputs on how assets are selected for the sake of portfolio optimization are welcome as well!

Yes, that is possible. In fact, this possibility (and its likelihood) was made well-known by this paper:
@ARTICLE{DeMiguel2007,
  author  = {Victor {DeMiguel} and Lorenzo Garlappi and Raman
             Uppal},
  title   = {Optimal versus Naive Diversification: How
             Inefficient is the 1/{N} Portfolio Strategy?},
  journal = {Review of Financial Studies},
  year    = 2009,
  volume  = 22,
  pages   = {1915--1953},
  number  = 5
}

And it's even simple to demonstrate.  Let's use a dataset of 5 industries, as provided by Kenneth French (https://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/Data_Library/det_5_ind_port.html).  I'll fetch it into R.
library("NMOF")
library("PMwR")
library("zoo")
P <- French(tempdir(),
            "5_Industry_Portfolios_daily_CSV.zip",
            price.series = TRUE)
P <- P[row.names(P) >= "2014-01-01", ]
timestamp <- as.Date(row.names(P))

The 5 columns of P should look like this:

Now I run two backtests. First, maximum Sharpe, using the maxSharpe implementation in NMOF. For simplicity, I assume a risk-free rate of zero. As expected returns, I'll use the mean returns of the previous 21 days.
(And this is the key problem.) Whenever these are negative, I replace them by 0.01%. Otherwise, the optimization typically fails, as the portfolio should not exist: everyone would hold risk-free investments.
## maximum sharpe optimisation/backtest
signal <- function() {
    C <- Close(n = 21)
    R <- returns(C)
    w <- maxSharpe(m = pmax(colMeans(R), 0.0001),
                   var = cov(R),
                   wmin = 0)
    w
}
bt <- btest(list(as.matrix(P)),
            signal = signal,
            do.signal = "endofmonth",
            convert.weights = TRUE,
            initial.cash = 100,
            timestamp = timestamp,
            b = 21   ## burnin 21 observations
            )
summary(as.NAVseries(bt, title = "max Sharpe"))
## ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————
## max Sharpe 
## 31 Jan 2014 ==> 30 Apr 2024   (2579 data points, 0 NAs)
##         100         303.588
## ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————
## Return (%)             11.4  (annualised)
## ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————
## Volatility (%)         15.2  (annualised)
## _ upside               12.5
## _ downside              9.1
## ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————
## High                 311.34  (09 Apr 2024)
## Low                   95.34  (11 Apr 2014)
## ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————
## Max. drawdown (%)      28.9
## _ peak               194.71  (19 Feb 2020)
## _ trough             138.50  (23 Mar 2020)
## _ recovery                   (05 Jun 2020)
## _ underwater now (%)    2.5
## ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————

And now equal weight.
ew <- function() {
    k <- ncol(Close())
    rep(1/k, k)
}
bt <- btest(list(as.matrix(P)),
            signal = ew,
            do.signal = "endofmonth",
            convert.weights = TRUE,
            initial.cash = 100,
            timestamp = timestamp,
            b = 21)
summary(as.NAVseries(bt, title = "equal weight"))
## ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————
## equal weight 
## 31 Jan 2014 ==> 30 Apr 2024   (2579 data points, 0 NAs)
##         100         302.199
## ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————
## Return (%)             11.4  (annualised)
## ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————
## Volatility (%)         15.0  (annualised)
## _ upside               12.2
## _ downside              9.4
## ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————
## High                 315.24  (28 Mar 2024)
## Low                   96.69  (11 Apr 2014)
## ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————
## Max. drawdown (%)      33.9
## _ peak               195.59  (19 Feb 2020)
## _ trough             129.26  (23 Mar 2020)
## _ recovery                   (07 Aug 2020)
## _ underwater now (%)    4.1
## ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————

So in this simple example, equal-weight has a (slightly) higher ratio of return/volatility than maximum Sharpe-ratio.
As I said above, this result is typically driven by using historical realized returns as expected returns. There is a fairly-old strand of literature that documents this effect. See for instance:
@ARTICLE{,
  author  = {George M. Frankfurter and Herbert E. Phillips and
             John P. Seagle},
  title   = {Portfolio Selection: The Effects of Uncertain Means,
             Variances, and Covariances},
  journal = {Journal of Financial and Quantitative Analysis},
  year    = 1971,
  volume  = 6,
  pages   = {1251--1262},
  number  = 5
}

@ARTICLE{,
  author  = {Best, Michael J. and Grauer, Robert R.},
  title   = {On the Sensitivity of Mean--Variance-Efficient
             Portfolios to Changes in Asset Means: Some
             Analytical and Computational Results},
  journal = {Review of Financial Studies},
  year    = 1991,
  volume  = 4,
  pages   = {315--342},
  number  = 2
}

Volatility is more persistent and can be controlled.
One can demonstrate this by only minimizing variance:
mv <- function() {
    C <- Close(n = 21)
    minvar(var = cov(returns(R)), wmin = 0)
}
bt <- btest(list(as.matrix(P)),
            signal = signal,
            do.signal = "endofmonth",
            convert.weights = TRUE,
            initial.cash = 100,
            timestamp = timestamp,
            b = 21)
summary(as.NAVseries(bt, title = "minimum variance"))
## ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————
## minimum variance 
## 31 Jan 2014 ==> 30 Apr 2024   (2579 data points, 0 NAs)
##         100         361.781
## ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————
## Return (%)             13.4  (annualised)
## ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————
## Volatility (%)         13.6  (annualised)
## _ upside               11.9
## _ downside              7.6
## ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————
## High                 375.36  (28 Mar 2024)
## Low                   98.73  (11 Apr 2014)
## ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————
## Max. drawdown (%)      28.1
## _ peak               197.44  (19 Feb 2020)
## _ trough             141.94  (23 Mar 2020)
## _ recovery                   (05 Jun 2020)
## _ underwater now (%)    3.6
## ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————

See also https://enricoschumann.net/files/note1N_MV.pdf .
(Disclosure: I am the maintainer of packages NMOF and PMwR.)

Hi Enrico, thank you for the amazing answer! Are you saying that evidence of how the minimum-variance case works is via its higher return/vol ratio = 13.4/13.6 ~= 0.98 vs the mean-variance cases that are around 0.75? Additionally, if my minimum-variance optimization has a poorer performance than an equal-weighted portfolio, that would indicate that something is "off" right?

In this simple example, yes, the return/vol ratio is higher. And I was confident to show such an example because for equities there is a vast amount of literature that documents the high risk-adjusted returns for minimum-variance, and so these kinds of examples usually work. (For other asset classes, there is less literature.) Search for "low risk anomaly" or similar terms. For min-variance versus equal-weight, I would first check if the oos variance of min-variance is lower then for equal weight. But with very few assets, there might well be cases in which equal-weight beats min-variance.
